# What is Splunk architecture?

Tags: architecture, splunk

I am unable to find proper architecture diagram for Splunk. I tried looking for the architecture diagram of Splunk but I was not able to find proper explanation for this.

Answer (score 6):

Were you looking for information on Splunk's internal architecture, or how to architect a deployment?

For deploying Splunk:  [Splunk Deployment](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Deploy/Distributedoverview)

Here's a link to a free 1-hour architecture self-training course: [Splunk Architecture Overview](http://www.splunk.com/view/SP-CAAAHSJ)

Here's a link to the Splunk documentation on the internal processes and components: [Splunk Enterprise architecture and processes](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Installation/Splunksarchitectureandwhatgetsinstalled)
And also a simpler explanation: [A Bit About Architecture](http://www.splunk.com/view/SP-CAAABF9)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for some deployment architectures/topologies, have a look at this Splunk document:
http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.5.0/Forwarding/Forwarderdeploymenttopologies